# React <input> value will not change when edit

Tags: reactjs, input

I'm trying to have an edit page to update the details of the existing object. I have some input elements to contain the value. But when I rendered the page, the values displayed in the input boxes will not allow me to change in view - when I delete or type in new, the values in the boxes will never change. Can anyone help to figure out the matter?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Sidebar from "../components/Sidebar";
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {useNavigate, useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import Axios from "axios";
import axios from "axios";

function CourseEdit() {
    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const [fname, setFname] = useState("");
    const [lname, setLname] = useState("");
    const [gender, setGender] = useState("");
    const [age, setAge] = useState("");
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
    const [payment, setPayment] = useState("0");

    const [student, setStudent] = useState({});
    const {id} = useParams();

    const editStudent = (id) => {
        Axios.put('http://localhost:3001/student_edit', {
            fname: fname,
            lname: lname,
            gender: gender,
            age: age,
            description: description,
            payment: payment,
            id: id,
        }).then(() => {
            alert('Student updated');
            navigate(`../students/detail/${id}`);
            console.log("student updated");
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/students/${id}`).then((response) => {
            setStudent(response.data[0]);
            // console.log(response.data[0].id);
        })},[id]);

    return (
        <div className="grid-container">
            <Sidebar/>
            <div className="main_content grid-2">
                <div className="details">
                    <div className="icon" style={{color: "#f7931e"}}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon="user"/> Edit STUDENT
                        <div className="back-button" onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="arrow-alt-circle-left"/>BACK
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="detail-content" style={{marginTop: "1.2em"}}>
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td className="td-left" style={{width: "100%"}}>
                                    <label htmlFor="StudentName">Student First Name:</label>
                                </td>
                                <td className="td-right" style={{width: "85%"}}>
                                    <input className="mb" type="text" name="studentFname" id="detail_input"
                                           value={student.fname} onChange={(event) => {
                                        setFname(event.target.value)
                                    }} required/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td className="td-left" style={{width: "100%"}}>
                                    <label htmlFor="StudentName">Student Last Name:</label>
                                </td>
                                <td className="td-right" style={{width: "85%"}}>
                                    <input className="mb" type="text" name="studentLname" id="detail_input"
                                           onChange={(event) => {
                                               setLname(event.target.value)
                                           }} value={student.lname} required/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            ...
                            ...
                            ...
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                        <div>
                            <button className="green_bt option_list round mr" onClick={() => {editStudent(`${id}`)}}>Save
                            </button>
                            <button className="red_bt option_list round mr" onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>Cancel
                            </button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CourseEdit;
```

Comment: You are never changing `student.lvalue` so it never changes. Either use `defaultValue` or change `student.lvalue`

Answer (score 0):

To set a **default value** for an input element in React:

**1 -** Pass the default value as a parameter to the useState hook for controlled fields.

**2 -** Set the defaultValue prop on uncontrolled input fields

in your case you're using controlled input  so you have to pass the default to useState like this :

```
 const [fname, setFname] = useState(student.fname);
 const [lname, setLname] = useState(student.lname);
```

*and change the input field like this :*

```
<input className="mb" type="text" name="studentFname" id="detail_input"
    value={fname} onChange={(event) => { setFname(event.target.value)}} 
        required/>
```

**and  :**

```
<input className="mb" type="text" name="studentLname" id="detail_input"
     onChange={(event) => {setLname(event.target.value)}} value={lname} 
     required/>
```

Comment: Hi monim, if I put `defaultValue= {student.fname}` the values of the object will be displayed in the input boxes, but if I didn't change the values, just leave them as original, those input boxes with original values will pass null data to back-end. if added `value={fname}`, the boxes will be empty.

Comment: I updated my answer you can check it now

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I modified the values in useState, and move the `const [fname, setFname] = useState(student.fname);
 const [lname, setLname] = useState(student.lname);` part behind the `useEffect` hook. But the input boxes will be blank, and when I save the update, it will pass `null` values to back-end. Looks like the `student.fname` in the `useState` is not defined or didn't gei any value?

Comment: Could you provide a codesandbox it will help

Comment: I'm a beginner, not very familiar to use the codesandbox. I put some relative code here https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-water-5sny7e?file=/src/pages/StudentEdit.js, but there has some error, I'm not sure if this works for you. If you want to see other codes to help me troubleshoot, please let me know. Thanks alot.